# How to import external library in angular2?

Tags: angular, import, external

I am following this (https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/)  to import external library. However I can’t mimic it the same way. I got the following error,

GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/rxjs/Subject 404 (Not Found).

Inside src, folder, I have two folders, app and js and two files, index.html and tsconfig.json.

App.ts

```
declare var jsSHA: any;

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app/app.html",
    directives: []
})

class App {

    shaObj: any;
    hash: String;

    constructor() {
        this.shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-512", "TEXT");
        this.shaObj.update("This is a test");
        this.hash = this.shaObj.getHash("HEX");
    }

}

bootstrap(App, []);
```

app.html

```
<h1>SHA-512 Hash</h1>

<p>String: This is a test</p>
<p>HEX: {{hash}}</p>
```

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
        <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
        <script src="js/sha.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.config({
                packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
            });
            System.import('app/app');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    </body>
</html>
```

system.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
            'underscore': 'node_modules/underscore/underscore.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './app.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

If someone have any clue about this problem, please give me advice.

Comment: Looks like somewhere is your `ts` files you import `rxjs/Subject`, but it's not properly configured through SystemJs.

Comment: What do you mean by import?

Comment: No, I do not export rxjs anywhere. The app.ts and app.html are all the files I have included in this project.

Comment: Import means that I want to use jsSHA library in my typescript file like the code in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If your `sha.js` is your own written module, you should add `sha.d.ts` file in order to import it in your app: 
[guide fo this](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/contributing-to-definitelytyped)

If it is an external library, install it as a regular npm package:

```
npm install —save sha
```